# CGRect not being applied

Tags: ios, swift, frame, cgrect

My code runs, but the problem is the `tab` image isn't being relocated to where I have it set in the code. It is staying where it is in the `viewController` and not getting any bigger or moving. I am trying to make it larger.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tab: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

if UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone4,1" {

        tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 122, width: 60, height: 60)

    } else if UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone5,1"  {
        tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 171, width: 75, height: 75)

    }
}
```

Comment: That is just a code snippet that will never get executed on itself. Is this inside a function?

Comment: do you use autolayout?

Comment: @matiastofteby It isn't inside a function.

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov I have used auto layout but I can't get it so the image will resize to those dimensions when it is run on different devices.

Comment: If you used auto-layout, you need to add `IBOutlet` to the `NSConstraint` for top, left, right, width, height (all dependent on what you want to modify).. then do `constraint.constant = XXXX` where XXXX is whatever value you want to set. You can't modify the frame of an auto-layout view unless you do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.. and even then it's not a good idea.

Comment: Could you specifie your question ? Do you want an animation which moves the tab on the y axis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **if** conditions will be false and hence code will never be executed, this is because **UIDevice.current.model** will return either *"iPhone"*, *"iPod touch"* or *"iPad"* and not the hardware model. The correct way to do it is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)

    // Retrive the device model
    let model = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine).children.reduce("") { model, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return model }
        return model + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    if model == "iPhone4,1" {
        tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 122, width: 60, height: 60)
    } else if model == "iPhone5,1"  {
        tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 171, width: 75, height: 75)   
    }
}
```

> But this code will run only on an **iPhone 4s** or a **GSM iPhone 5** and will
>   not run on other devices like: a **CDMA iPhone 5** or an **iPhone 6** or any
>   other model including iPads.

Instead a more robust method will be checking the screen size, iPhone 4s and lower models have a screen size of **320x480** point, the iPhone 5 have a screen size of **320x568** point, other devices have greater screen sizes.

Instead of targeting a certain device we will target a certain size. So if the screen height is greater than **480** point we run the code inside the first if block otherwise we run the code on the second block as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 480 {
        tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 122, width: 60, height: 60)
    } else {
        tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 171, width: 75, height: 75)
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this is a very bad practice and you should use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
extension UIDevice {
    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }
        return identifier
    }
}
```

Then in your code call like this :

```
if UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone4,1" {
    tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 122, width: 60, height: 60)
} else if UIDevice.current.modelName == "iPhone5,1"  {
    tab.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 171, width: 75, height: 75)
}
```